# Populating Spring MVC form

Tags: forms, spring, spring-mvc

I have created the following Controller class:

```
package com.bilitutor.cct.control;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.bilitutor.cct.bean.*;
import com.bilitutor.cct.service.*;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public User getUserObect() {
      return new User();
    }

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Landing page. Just return the login.jsp
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(ModelMap model) {
        logger.info("home() called");
        model.addAttribute("emailErrorMessage", "Please enter Email");
        return "login";
    }

    /**
     * New User signup. If user already exists, send back the error, or send an email and forward to the email validation page
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String signup(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("user")User user, BindingResult result) {
        logger.info("signup() : email="+user.getEmail()+" pass="+user.getPassword()+" accessCode="+user.getAccessCode());
        try {
            userService.addUser(user);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            logger.info("Email already exists");
            model.addAttribute("emailErrorMessage", "Email already exists");
        }
        return "login";
    }

}
```

And the following JSP

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<html>
<body>

<form:form id="mainForm" method="post" commandName="user">
<table id="mainTable">

    <tr id="emailRow"><td rowspan="2" class="lrPadding">Email</td><td class="lrPadding"><form:input id="email" path="email" class="editable"/></td></tr>
    <tr id="emailErrorRow"><td id="emailError" class="errorMessage">${emailErrorMessage}</td></tr>

</table>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

When I load the page for the first time, I can see the message "Please Enter Email" on my login.jsp . Upon hitting the /signup method with an existing email, I can see the "Email already exists" log message on the login page thus returned, but the message "Please Enter Email" stays. Can someone figure out the reason. Is it possible that the login.jsp is compiled only once and gets cached somewhere when I call it for the first time, and what I am seeing as a result of hitting /signup is the cached page. If so, how can I get around this.

The html of the login page that appears after hitting the signup() method is:

```
<html style="background-image:url('/cct/resources/images/wallpaper.jpg')">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/cct/resources/css/master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/cct/resources/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/cct/resources/js/login.js"></script>
    <title>BiliTutor Content Creator Toolkit</title>
</head>
<body>

 <h3> emailErrorMessage = Please enter Email</h3>

<form id="mainForm" action="/cct/" method="post">
<table id="mainTable" class="contents roundBox">

    <tr id="logoRow"><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;padding:20px;width:300px;height:100px"><img id="imgLogo" src="/cct/resources/images/logo.png"></td></tr>

    <tr id="emailRow"><td rowspan="2" class="lrPadding">Email&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class="lrPadding"><input id="email" name="email" class="editable" type="text" value=""/></td></tr>
    <tr id="emailErrorRow"><td id="emailError" class="errorMessage">Please enter Email</td></tr>

    <tr id="passwordRow"><td rowspan="2" class="lrPadding">Password</td><td class="lrPadding"><input id="password" name="password" class="editable" type="password" value=""/></td></tr>
    <tr id="passwordErrorRow"><td id="passwordError" class="errorMessage">Password should be atleast 8 char long</td></tr>

    <tr id="confirmPasswordRow"><td rowspan="2" class="lrPadding">Confirm<br/>Password</td><td class="lrPadding"><input id="confirmPassword" type="password" class="editable"/></td></tr>
    <tr id="confirmPasswordErrorRow"><td id="confirmPasswordError" class="errorMessage">Passwords dont match</td></tr>

    <tr id="accessCodeRow"><td rowspan="2" class="lrPadding">Access<br/>Code</td><td class="lrPadding"><input id="accessCode" name="accessCode" class="editable" type="text" value=""/></td></tr>
    <tr id="accessCodeErrorRow"><td id="accessCodeError" class="errorMessage">Access Code must be atleast 8 char long</td></tr>

    <tr id="buttonsRow"><td colspan="2"><table style="margin:0px;margin-top:1em;padding:0px;width:100%"><tr>
        <td><div id="btnNewUser" class="button" style="float:left">New Tutor<br/>Signup</div></td>
        <td><div id="btnForgotPassword" class="button">Forgot<br/>Password</div></td>
        <td><div id="btnLogin" class="button" style="float:right">Tutor<br/>Login</div></td>
    </tr></table></td></tr>

</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and my IDE looks like:

[image]

Comment: You are definitely seeing the log statement "Email already exists" printed?

Comment: Yes, I can see the log but not the actual error

Comment: can you post the result as html source?

Comment: I have just put the html result and the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I would change the method signature to

```
public String signup(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("user")User user, BindingResult result) {
```

add your error directly to the model

```
  } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        logger.info("Email already exists");
        model.addAttribute("emailErrorMessage", "Email already exists");
    }
    return "login";
```

and then access it like so in the jsp

```
<tr id="emailErrorRow"><td id="emailError" class="errorMessage">${emailErrorMessage}</td></tr>
```

Comment: That didnt change much. I have edited my post about. See if this could give a better clue.

Comment: Have you tried printing ${emailErrorMessage} on its own, outside the table and the css imposed by class="errorMessage", maybe just inside teh body tag? Plus, @Ralph is right, you should use BindingResult for form errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `BindingResult result` instead of an own error map:

```
bindingResult.rejectValue("email", "errorMessageCode", "Email already exists");
```